# How do I calculate equilibrium temperature of a pot of water with some food in it, knowing only the equilibrium temperature of the pot of water?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, thermal-conductivity, food

Say I have a pot with 3L water on a stovetop, at an equilibrium temperature of 75ºC. I then add 1kg of meat at 20ºC to it. How do I calculate the final equilibrium temperature I should expect the pot's content to reach?

(Assume the pot is covered so it doesn't lose as much heat to the environment.)

I came up with the following reasoning somewhere else, but people have been telling me specific heat isn't relevant for the question:

> Most foods' specific heat is around 3 kJ/KgºC, and waters' is around 4
> kJ/KgºC. I suppose that means given the same heat input, food will
> heat up about 1.33x more than water?
>
> And thus a pot with, say, 3kg water and 1kg of meat (assuming a
> specific heat of 3 kJ/KgºC for the meat), all the stuff in the pot
> will have an average specific heat of 3.25 kJ/KgºC (3+3+3+4=13,
> divided by 4kg = 3.25), so it will all heat up 1.08x more?
>
> What exactly does heating up 1.08x more mean, though? Do I just
> multiply 75ºC by 1.08? Surely not, right? Do I need to stick 1.08 in
> some formula or convert it to kelvin or something? What even are
> numbers, really?

My reasoning was that applying the same heat to something that requires less energy to heat up would make it hotter than something that requires more. If this isn't how you do it, could you point me to the right direction on how to calculate it?

Comment: Based on Chemomechanics comment on my answer, please clarify something for me. Prior to putting the meat into the water, is its temperature the same as the water or different?

Comment: The meat would be at room temperature in this scenario, let's say 20C if you need it to be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equilibrium temperature of your heated, capped pot is essentially independent of what's inside it. The equilibrium or steady-state solution is governed by the energy input and output flow:

- The input energy flow depends on the heat source, which presumably remains unchanged.
- The output energy flow depends on the geometry and material properties of the pot and the surrounding environment (most notably, the difference between the external pot temperature and the ambient temperature), which also remain constant.

However, the greater the heat capacity of the cooler material added to the pot, the longer it will take to return to its equilibrium temperature.

Put another way, the specific heat generally doesn't appear in steady-state problems with a heat source or sink because this material property involves temperature changes, which are absent for those problems.